# Displacement from acceleration in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a doubt working with Simulink to carry out the integration of an acceleration to obtain the speed and then the displacement.

The thing is that I actually know the value ​​that the displacement has to finally give, and it's not the same thing that I get by integrating.

However, if I derive the displacement calculated and the correct displacement I obtain two velocities that are equal and coincide with the velocity calculated from the integration of the acceleration. In the same way if I derive this two velocities I obtain the same accelrations that are the same with the original one.

I think the mistake must be in the constant term that is generated integrating but I am quite confused with  the results coinciding so well when I derive from an erroneous value.

Does anyone know how I could solve this error and effectively get the displacement? Is it possible knowing only the acceleration?

I attach images of both the assembly and the results obtained.

Greetings and thanks in advance

pic1. Assembly
[image: 1]

pic2. Acceleration: Original, Obtained from the speed from the wrong displacement, Obtained from the speed from the correct displacement
[image: 2]

pic3. Velocities: Integrated from original acceleration, Obtained from the wrong displacement, Obtained from the speed from the correct displacement.
[image: 3]

pic4. Displacement: Corrrect displacement, Obtained displacement. 
[image: 4]

Comment: My initial guess would be incorrect IC. What initial conditions have you specified in your two integrator blocks?

Comment: Both of them has initial conditions zero as it is initially at rest.

Comment: That doesn't really agree with your "-0.5" constant that you add to your "corrected" position.

Comment: That is because my sensor is at a height of 0.5, but I dont really want to know the height of it but the displacement it sufers through the process. If I add that initial condition of 0.5 I get the same result but with 0.5 more.